# change AMP story shopping fields

Tags: amp-story, amp-stories

How do I translate or change the names of the "buy now" and "details" fields in amp story shopping, I'm implementing it here. but the examples are too vague. in amp-story-shopping-attachment templates > Product details page (PDP)

I tried to change the fields to customized texts in Portuguese, but nothing works. many documents and pages with images and general details of amp.dev are offline.
I seek to change the fields and do more